# Advantages of an empty class in C++

Tags: c++, class

What could be the possible advantages/uses of having an empty class?

P.S: 
This question might sound trivial to some of you but it is just for learning purpose and has no practical significance. FYI googling didn't help.

Comment: There are a couple situations where that can be useful; can you give an example, so we can have some context?

Comment: Empty as in no members or functions; or empty like using the Null Object pattern?

Comment: did you see this link http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/8370/ ?

Comment: Empty as in no members or functions.

Comment: @Ron, Do you mean really empty class, like class Empty{}; ? Well, I never had chance to use it.

Comment: Remember that, if you substantiate a class with no members or functions, it still takes at least one byte of memory.

Comment: @bjskishore : Yes I did see that link. Didn't help because the attempt to explanation wasn't accompanied with code snippets.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why are C++ classes allowed to have zero data members?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382922/why-are-c-classes-allowed-to-have-zero-data-members)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One use would be in template (meta-)programming: for instance, [iterator tags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) are implemented as empty classes. The only purpose here is to pass around information at compilation time so you can check, if an iterator passed to e.g. a template function meets specific requirements.

**EXAMPLE:**

This is *really* simplified, just to ge an idea. Here the purpose of the tag class is to decide, which implementation of an algorithm to use:

```
class forward_iterator_tag {};
class random_access_iterator_tag {};

class MySimpleForwardIterator {
public:
  typedef typename forward_iterator_tag tag;
  // ...
};

class MySimpleRandomIterator {
public:
  typedef typename random_access_iterator_tag tag;
  // ...
};

template<class iterator, class tag>
void myfunc_int(iterator it, tag t) {
  // general implementation of myfunc
}

template<class iterator>
void myfunc_int<iterator, forward_iterator_tag>(iterator it) {
  // Implementation for forward iterators
}

template<class iterator>
void myfunc_int<iterator, random_access_iterator_tag>(iterator it) {
  // Implementation for random access iterators
}

template<class iterator>
void myfunc(iterator it) {
  myfunc_int<iterator, typename iterator::tag>(it);
}
```

(I hope I got this right, it's been a while since I used this ...)

With this code, you can call `myfunc` on an arbitrary iterator, and let the compiler choose the correct implementation depending on the iterator type (i.e. tag).

Comment: look at the implementation of some STL iterator, you should have the code in any compiler

Comment: The idiom is called [tag dispatching](https://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching).

Answer (score 5):

The following can be used to have a `boost::variant` which can hold an (SQL) NULL value for example.

```
class Null { };

typedef boost::variant<Null, std::string, int> Value;
```

To make it more useful things like `operator==` and `operator<<` are handy. For example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &lhs, const Null &rhs)
{
     lhs << "*NULL*";
     return lhs;
}

int main()
{
    Variant v("hello");
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    v = Null();
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

Will give:

```
hello
*NULL*
```

Answer (score 3):

In the STL, Standard Template Library of the C++, for example you have

```
template<class _Arg,
 class _Result>
struct unary_function
    { // base class for unary functions
 typedef _Arg argument_type;
 typedef _Result result_type;
    };
```

When defining a functor, you can inherit unary_function, and then you have the typedef defined automatically at your disposal.

Answer (score 2):

An empty class could be used as a "token" defining something unique; in certain patterns, you want an implementation-agnostic representation of a unique instance, which has no value to the developer other than its uniqueness. One example is Unit of Work; you may not care one bit about what's going on inside your performer, but you want to tell that performer that the tasks you're telling it to perform are part of an atomic set. An empty class representing the Unit of Work to the outside world may be perfect in this case; almost anything a Unit of Work object could store or do (encapsulating a DB transaction, exposing Commit/Rollback behaviors) would start tying you to a particular implementation, but an object reference is useful to provide a unique but copyable and passable reference to the atomic set of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like a placeholder for checking purpose or as enabler to special functionality. For example in Java exist the "empty" interface Serializable used to specify if a class is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

"empty" classes means classes which have no data members?
They typically declare typedefs or member functions, and you can extend them with your own classes.

Comment: (english is not my native language) 
pseudocode
class Shape
{
virtual double area();
}

class Circle extend Shape
{
double area()
}

class Square extend Shape
{
double area()
}

Comment: You can edit your answer by selecting the 'edit' button and put the code example there instead of in the comments.  This makes it a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382922/why-are-c-classes-allowed-to-have-zero-data-members) is an interesting link with answers to why its allowed.  You might find this helpful to find situations where it might be useful.

Comment: The article you mention speaks about no *data* members. Classes that have only function members are widely used (e.g. for interface definition). I think the OP meant empty classes without *any* members.

Comment: @MartinStettner - The post I have in this questions refers to why its allowed.  The other article I posted was to show where Javi's answer came from.  Reading the article you see the answer verbatim in the article.  I wasnt posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, often an empty class (or struct) is used a placeholder, a differentiator, a token, etc.

For example, a lot of people are unaware that there are "nothrow" versions of operator new.  The syntax to invoke *nothrow new* is:

```
p = new(std::nothrow) Bar;
```

and std::nothrow is defined simply as

```
struct nothrow_t {}; //defined in namespace std
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [MartinStettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81424/martinstettner) is fine though just to highlight an important point here: The concept of iterator tags or for that matter any tags in C++, is not strictly dependent on empty classes. The C++ tags, if stl writers would have wanted to, could well have been non-empty classes; that should work but then it won't add any additional value; at least for compile time acrobatics that it is usually reserved for.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of `typeid`

Suppose we have comparable interface `Id`. We need fill some container with unique instances of this interface. How to guarantee the uniqueness of `Id` instances produced by independent software parts? «Independent parts» means some different dynamic libraries, compiled by different programmers from different locations

One of decisions is to compare `typeid` of some type first. If `typeid` matches, convert and compare other implementation specific properties. C++ language guarantees uniqueness of any type within process memory. Which type should be used for this purpose? Any type with minimum resource consumption — empty one