# Why does inheriting not increase the size, but a member does?

Tags: c++, inheritance, member

Take a look at these three classes (includes ommited):

```
template<class T> struct A {
    std::allocator<T> allocator;
    T* ptr;
};

template<class T> struct B {
    T* ptr;
    std::allocator<T> allocator;
};

template<class T> struct C : std::allocator<T> {
    T* ptr;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "A: " << sizeof(A<int>) << "\n";
    std::cout << "B: " << sizeof(B<int>) << "\n";
    std::cout << "C: " << sizeof(C<int>) << "\n";
}
```

If you'd ask me, depending on alignment, either `A` or `B` has to have the same size as `C`. However, printing the `sizeof` claims otherwise:

```
A: 16
B: 16
C: 8
```

Why is this so?

Comment: `std::allocator<T>` has no member variables itself, so if you use it as a base class, the EBO (empty base optimization) is applied. As a member, no such optimization is (AFAIK) allowed.

Comment: @DanielFrey So when making a container should I make a `detail` member class, which contains all data members and inherits from the allocator template argument in order to minimize container size?

Comment: @nightcracker: That's how almost every standard library class is implemented...

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks, that's so ugly though =/

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4789929/14065

Comment: Compressed-pair much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By C++11, 9/4:

> Complete objects and member subobjects of class type shall have nonzero size.

No such restriction applies to base classes, as long as every object has  a unique *pair* of type and address. So as long as the "first" data member hasn't got the same type as a base subobject, the base subobject may have zero size, being neither complete nor a member.

(I put "first" in quotation marks since there's a complication involving access levels.)

In fact, 1.8/5–6 formalize the above:

> 5 Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more bytes of storage. **Base class subobjects may have zero size.** An object of trivially copyable or standard-layout type (3.9) shall occupy contiguous bytes of storage.
>
> 6 Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses.

---

Here's a "typical" implementation of `std::vector`, minus all the name mangling:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc>
class vector
{
    struct vbase : Alloc
    {
        T * data, * end, * capacity;
        vbase(Alloc const & a) : Alloc(a), data(), end(), capacity() { }
    };

    vbase impl;

public:
    vector(Alloc const & a = Alloc()) : impl(a) { }

    T * data() const { return impl.data; }
    T & operator[](size_t n) { return data()[n]; }

    // ...

    // use impl.allocate(), impl.construct() etc.
};
```

This basically ensures that `sizeof(vector<T>) == 3 * sizeof(T*)` whenever the allocator is empty.

Comment: I assume an anonymous class `impl` would work the same without any issues?

Comment: @nightcracker: How would you write the constructors for an anonymous class?