# Why is sizeof empty class 1?

Tags: c++

If sizeof empty class is 1 byte then why is sizeof class having int data member not 5 bytes?

```
class A
{
    int a;
};

class B
{
};    

int main()
{
  std::cout << sizeof(A)<< ":" << sizeof(B) << "\n";
}
```

I know the expected output is 4 : 1 but just want to know why sizeof(A) is 4 byte not 5 byte. what happens to that 1 byte which helps to distinguish different object address?

Comment: It is not needed anymore

Comment: @SidS Objects cannot have a size of zero.

Comment: @Sid S: `sizeof` is never 0 in C++ and in C. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632021/can-sizeof-return-0-zero

Comment: @SidS `sizeof(T) > 0` for any type `T`. There ain't no such thing as a zero-size type.

Comment: [what is the size of empty class in c java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789910/what-is-the-size-of-empty-class-in-c-java). I hope this will help you.

Comment: @SidS `sizeof` doesn't give you a different answer if you call it on a type instead of an expression.

Answer (score 1):

If a class has no data members, the compiler pretends it contains an invisible member variable of type `char`, which gives it a size of 1.

In the case of your `class A`, there is a data member (`int a;`), so this special case doesn't apply. Nothing is added.

The special case is only needed because otherwise the compiler could place multiple zero-size objects at the same memory location. But if a class has data members, its size can't be zero, so nothing special happens.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is sizeof empty class 1?

This is because every object is guaranteed to have a unique address (exceptions apply). In order for an array of N objects to have N objects with unique address, they must be stored 1 byte apart. By definition, this distance is the size of the class. 1 byte is the minimum possible size for any type.

Classes can contain padding that is not part of any sub-object. An empty class contains a single byte of padding.

> then why sizeof class having int data member is not 5 bytes?

Because a non-empty class doesn't need padding to guarantee the uniqueness of the address of the object. In particular, a class with a single `int` member doesn't require any padding.

Non-empty classes may need padding for another reason though: Alignment. For example, a class:

```
class C {
    alignas(4) int i;
    char c;
};
```

will have the size 8 (3 bytes padding) in order to satisfy the alignment requirement of the member `i`.