# How is an empty class and an empty struct compiled?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compiler-construction, clang

Does the C++ standard dictate the compilation layout of the class and struct? How are they compiled differently especially if they are empty?

Comment: Absolutelu "no" on both counts to the first question.  A class has an implicit "this" pointer in answer to the second question.

Comment: @paulsm4:  Your answer to the second question is wrong.  there is no dofference between a `class` and a `struct` in this regard.  To wit, a `struct` can have `virtual` members.

Comment: Classes and structs are the exact same thing, the only difference is with default access specification (for members and bases).

Comment: @paulsm4 If there is no code there is nowhere for the implicit 'this' pointer to be generated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does in a way, it says that it has to allocate space for it unless certain cases when its used as a base class *(known as Empty Base Class Optimization)*. This is to guarantee that different objects have different addresses.

They are compiled the same given that `struct` and `class` are the same thing, except for the default access specifier. In **C++11** the notion of *standard-layout* classes/structs is introduced, and guarantees that the memory layout for empty classes to be the same.

Comment: Is it specified anywhere how much space is allocated? 1 byte?

Comment: @Paranaix: As far as I know, is not specified. It could be more than 1 byte to satisfy alignment requirements.

Comment: The size of reference would be architecture dependant. One address on x86 would be 32 bits.

Comment: I thought they added char to an empty class and performed alignments depending on the architecture?

Comment: @kunj2aan: Sounds like a sensible implementation, but the standard does not mandate it.

Comment: @Paranaix: Take a look at my similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271673/can-there-be-a-c-type-that-takes-0-bytes

Comment: @kunj2aan Who is this __they__ you refer to?